# placing img attached to post into a bootstrap carousel Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I`m trying to put post images to wordpress carousel by code below, and some jquery to add active class, but it doesnt work, tried everything and search everything anyone can help?

```
<?php 
    $attachments = get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID );
foreach($attachments as $attachment) {
$img_full = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'full');
if($img !== false) {
?>

<div class="item">
   <img src="<?php echo $img[0]; ?>" />
</div>

<?php
 }
  }
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$("carousel-inner .item:first").addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you try `$(".carousel-inner .item:first").addClass("active");`. Added a dot at the very beginning so that it will look like `.carousel-inner`

Comment: unbelievable - it works, thanks:-)

Comment: thats good @Artur...!

Comment: Your script is not WordPress "safe".  WordPress loads jQuery in no-conflict mode which means that you can't use the `$` to call jQuery.  Modify your document ready like so, which lets you use the `$` *inside* the document ready:   

`<script>
jQuery(function($) {
$("carousel-inner .item:first").addClass("active");
});`

Comment: thanks, I didn`t know about it